# Error in creating dataframe: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Tuple2 is not a valid external type for schema of string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have created a schema with following code

```
val schema=  new StructType().add("city", StringType, true).add("female", IntegerType, true).add("male", IntegerType, true)
```

Created a RDD from

```
val data = spark.sparkContext.textFile("cities.txt")
```

Converted to RDD of Row to apply schema

```
    val cities = data.map(line => line.split(";")).map(row => Row.fromSeq(row.zip(schema.toSeq)))


 val citiesRDD = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(cities, schema)
```

This gives me an error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Tuple2 is not a valid external type for schema of string
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a schema to create a `Row`, you need the schema when you create the `DataFrame`. You also need to introduce some logic how to convert your splitted line (which produces 3 strings) into integers:

here a minimal solution without exception-handling:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq("Bern;10;12")) // mock for real data

val schema = new StructType().add("city", StringType, true).add("female", IntegerType, true).add("male", IntegerType, true)

val cities = data.map(line => {
val Array(city,female,male) = line.split(";")
  Row(
    city,
    female.toInt,
    male.toInt
  )
 }
)

val citiesDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(cities, schema)
```

I normally use case-classes to create a dataframe, because spark can infer the schema from the case class:

```
// "schema" for dataframe, define outside of main method
case class MyRow(city:Option[String],female:Option[Int],male:Option[Int]) 

val data = sc.parallelize(Seq("Bern;10;12")) // mock for real data

import sqlContext.implicits._

val citiesDF = data.map(line => {
val Array(city,female,male) = line.split(";")
  MyRow(
    Some(city),
    Some(female.toInt),
    Some(male.toInt)
  )
}
).toDF()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What if the number of columns are more then 300? What can be the best way?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Not sure about that, I just know there are certain limitiations in scala, e.g. prior to scala 2.11, case classes were limited to 22 fields (same with tuples). The first approach should still work, but maybe it's worthwile to think about using more complex column types (structs, arrays, maps) to reduce the number of columns...