# Explode Array[(Int, Int)] column from Spark Dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I want to explode Array[(Int, Int)]

INPUT:

```
colA newCol
1     [[11, 12],[13, 15]]
2     [[17, 91], [51, 72]]
```

OUTPUT:

```
colA newCol
1     11
1     13
2     17
2     51
```

My Schema looks like this:

```
 |-- colA: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- newCol: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- value: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
```

I've tried something below like this:

```
val res =  df.withColumn("tup", explode($"newCol")).select("colA", "tup")

res.select(col("colA"), col("tup")("value").as("uId"))
```

Comment: In your select statement just use tup.value to access the exploded column

Comment: @Aaron
It fails:
```java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp is not a valid external type for schema of struct<value:int,count:int>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
val result = df.withColumn("resultColumn",explode(col("newCol").getItem("value")).select("colA","resultColumn")
```

so you are basically exploding the array and then taking the first element of the struct.

Edited:

Here is how i created the dataframe with the same schema.

```
scala> import spark.implicits._

scala> val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List((1),(2))).toDF("id")

scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("col2",array(struct(lit(1),lit(2)),struct(lit(3),lit(4))))

scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- col2: integer (nullable = false)


scala> df1.withColumn("resultColumn",explode(col("col2").getItem("col1"))).select("id","resultColumn").show
+---+------------+
| id|resultColumn|
+---+------------+
|  1|           1|
|  1|           3|
|  2|           1|
|  2|           3|
+---+------------+
```

Comment: It still throws the same exception which i wrote above

This is what i did:

```df.withColumn("resultColumn",explode(col("newCol").getItem("value"))).select("colA","resultColumn").show()```

Comment: How are you creating the dataframe? It looks like something is wrong with the way you are creating the dataframe ( it's kind of weird because the schema looks good to me ). Let me edit my answer to add the dataframe creation code.

Comment: This is how I generate data frame:

```import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val data = Seq(
      Row(1, Array((1,2), (2,3),(3,4))),
      Row(2, Array((1,2), (2,3),(3,4)))
    )

val schema = StructType(
      Array( StructField("colA", IntegerType),
        StructField("newCol", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
          StructField("value", IntegerType),
          StructField("count", IntegerType)))))))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
      schema)
```

Comment: @RajaSabarish  It's failing due to incompatibility between Scala's tuple and Spark struct datastructure. Yours dataframe is failing before running any transformation on it,  when trying to show the data ( df.show ). You might want to look for other ways ( using case classes or using toDF like i did) to create the dataframe.  Refer to this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805510/error-in-creating-dataframe-java-lang-runtimeexception-scala-tuple2-is-not-a-v?rq=1